# Open a div in parent window of iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page which has an iFrame to another page and what I am looking for is to click a button with this code inside the iframe:

```
<td class="id-center">                 
    <div class="bs-example">
        <a id="comments" href="comments.php?id=$id"  name="comments" value="$id" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg\" class="btn btn-primary btn-default center-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></a>
    </div> 
</td>
```

which can then open the following overlay pop up box in the parent window:

```
<!-- Large modal -->

<div style="width:90%;" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Add a comment</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Body of popup -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm doing this with Bootstrap 3. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

One way you could go about this is to open the modal through bootstrap's javascript api. The key to making this work is to use the iframe's `parent` attribute to access the parent document. You can check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qba8q6er/1/) to see what I mean. Unfortunately it's set up kind of strangely because the iframe can't access JSFiddles javascript window (or I just don't know how), but the content you would see in the iframe is embedded in its property `srcdoc`. Let me know if any of this needs any explaining.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "<div id='overlay' style='height: 100em;background-color:#000; opacity:0.4; width: 100%;z-index: 1000;position: fixed;'><div style='height: 100%;width: 70px;margin: auto;'><img src='/spinner.gif' style='height: 70px;margin-top: 40vh;'/></div></div>")
```

This will add overlay to your parent body but this will work only if both the pages in the same domain.